# Структура данных для z-index

Tags: структуры-данных, z-index, c++

Необходимо подобрать структуру данных для хранения данных z-index. Все индексы должны быть уникальными и для них должна быть определена операция сравнения. Операции со структурой: добавление индекса, который больше или меньше другого индекса, добавление индекса, большего максимального индекса, удаление индекса.

Comment: обычная трехмерная матрица подойдет?

Comment: @perfect можно подробнее?

Comment: @Im ieee просто z-index это обычно указатель глубины. например есть окно которое лежит поверх другого окна у него есть координаты в пространстве 1-я размерность матрицы указывает его расположение по горизонтали 2-я размерность указывает его положение по вертикали, а 3-я указывает на его положения в глубину (между другими окнами). так можно получить любой пиксел этого окна в любой момент времени

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен лишь список z-индексов (тогда базируйтесь на `std::set`), или z-index для группы объектов (тогда например `std::map<double, VisualObject*>`)?

---

Смотрите. Если у вас есть `std::set<double>`, то все операции выполняются просто.

1. Уникальность — свойство `std::set`.
2. Сравнимость: элементы типа `double` сравниваются «из коробки».
3. Добавление индекса после данного:

   - убеждаетесь, что элемент есть во множестве;
   - получаете следующий ([`upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/upper_bound));
   - подсчитываете среднее арифметическое этих элементов и вставляете во множество
4. добавление элемента меньше минимального: получаете минимальный ([`begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/begin), т. к. множество отсортировано), вставляете среднее арифметическое минимального и `DOUBLE_MIN`. То же для максимального.
5. Удаление из коробки.

Единственный «скользкий» случай — если при вычислении среднего арифметического в пункте 3 оно окажется равным одному из чисел. Такое может быть, если вы вставляете очень много элементов. В этом случае придётся перенумеровать все индексы: подсчитать количество элементов, и в `i`-ый по порядку элемент записать число `i`.

Comment: Просто список z-индексов. На мой взгляд, выбор контейнера — дело второстепенное, основная сложность в том, как при добавлении нового индекса избежать изменения значений большого количества соседних индексов. Наверняка же есть структуры для равномерного или близкого к равномерному распределения целых чисел.

Comment: @Im ieee, по крайней мере в Linux STL set реализован на rb-tree, поэтому добавление нового индекса стоит O(log N).

Кстати, обход по итератору происходит по порядку возрастания значений элементов.

Comment: @avp Ну а для двусвязного списка вообще O(1). Дело в другом: допустим, индекс это просто целое число. Тогда при добавлении индекса, большего какого-то другого индекса, если следующие несколько чисел-индексов заняты, то их придётся увеличить. Очевидно, необходимо, чтобы подобное увеличение (или уменьшение) происходило как можно реже.

Comment: @Im ieee, видимо, я не знаком с какой-то спецификой z-индексов

(мне казалось, что требуется добавлять **новые** элементы **в произвольные места** структуры, сохраняя ее упорядоченность).


А что Вам нужно на самом деле? 

(если можно, то объясните "на пальцах" (для дилетанта в этой области)).

Comment: @avp Так и есть, новые элементы в произвольные места структуры. Например, в плохой реализации, у нас есть двусвязный список индексов i1=1, i2=2, i3=3, i4=4. Нужно добавить индекс i больший i1 и меньший i2. Для этого нужно увеличить все индексы большие i1, то есть i2, i3 и i4, на 1, а i будет равно двум. Итоговый список индексов i1=1, i=2, i2=3, i3=4, i4=5.

Comment: @Im ieee, да, я кажется понял проблему. 

Если такой индекс уже есть, то в случае дерева придется удалять и потом добавлять M элементов (пересчитываемый непрерывный диапазон), а в случае списка придется долго искать место.

Первое, что приходит в голову   -- это дерево диапазонов (что-то похожее на индекс для mmap-нутых страниц в ядре, но тут надо думать ...)

Что Вы храните вместе с индексом? Хотя, это наверное не важно, скажем `void *`. Т.е. надо придумать, как эффективно реализовать этот вектор.

Вам какой-то общий случай нужен или есть конкретная статистика размера диапазонов?

Comment: @avp Если в случае списка хранить узел списка, то место искать не придется. Случай нужен общий. Дерево отрезков посмотрю, спасибо.

Comment: @Im ieee, @avp: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @VladD, не знаю, как Вы, а я думал явно не о [том z-index](http://htmlbook.ru/css/z-index), который, похоже, интересует @Im ieee.

Если это так, тогда понятно, зачем он хочет инкрементировать значения уже запомненных элементов.

Возможно, я не прав, но мне кажется, что на HTML странице не м.б. *очень* много элементов и тогда любой массив (или список) на практике по времени работы вполне подойдет (даже при линейном поиске).

Comment: @avp: Угу, вы правы. По сути нам нужно лишь линейное упорядочение элементов, поэтому числовые значения _не нужны_, нужен лишь список UI-объектов. Именно об этом я спросил в первом комментарии (до того, как его преобразовали в ответ): нужны ли сами объекты?